# Como faço uma url amigável com PHP?

Tags: php, htaccess, url

Eu gostaria de usar isso para mascarar os dados contidos na url,. algo parecido com:

> localhost/webservice/redes.php?parametro=1 por
>   localhost/webservice/redes/consultar/

como faço isso?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608031/how-to-hide-url-in-php

Comment: Não adianta... já fiz de todo jeito e sempre cai no erro 404

Comment: Usou Rewrite? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/?$ /$1.php [QSA,L] 
</IfModule>

Comment: Tente usar um micro Framework que já faça isso, aconselho o Flight,é bem fácil de usar:
http://flightphp.com/learn/

Comment: @GustavoCamargo Isso parece um tiro de canhão pra matar passarinho...